# Mapped drive link to UNC link for linked tables

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a `file dialog` to relinking tables to a backend and then changing the mapped drive connection string of the link tables to `UNC` links. However I haven't been that lucky, I have come through the following problems:

*1. The code below doesn't work as expected if the link is already a `UNC` link. I want to relink with the updated location.*

*2. Can the sub `uncLink` use a loop? I tried a `For` loop but without success.*

Please see below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DonarArea FROM tblDonations")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " Please locate data file!", , "Data file not found"
Call AttachDataFile
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub


Public Function AttachDataFile() As Boolean
Dim ofd As Object
Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(3)
ofd.AllowMultiSelect = False
ofd.Show
If ofd.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then

    result = RelinkTablesToBackend(ofd.SelectedItems(1))
    If result = vbCancel Then
        AttachDataFile = False
    End If
    AttachDataFile = True
Else
    AttachDataFile = False
End If
End Function

Function RelinkTablesToBackend(BackEndPath As String) As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim db As database
Dim tdfRefresh As TableDef
Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If tdf.Connect <> vbNullString Then
    On Error Resume Next
    db.TableDefs(tdf.Name).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & BackEndPath
    db.TableDefs(tdf.Name).RefreshLink
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    RelinkTablesToBackend = MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical + vbRetryCancel, "Error #:" & Err.Number)
               
    Exit Function
    End If

    End If
    Next

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
uncLink
End Function

Private Sub uncLink()
Dim strConn As String
Dim uncConn As String
Dim tdf As TableDef
strConn = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonations").Connect
uncConn = GetUNCLateBound(strConn)

CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonations").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & uncConn
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonations").RefreshLink
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblNew").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & uncConn
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblNew").RefreshLink
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & uncConn
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonatedItems").RefreshLink
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblWithAttachments").Connect = ";DATABASE=" & uncConn
CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblWithAttachments").RefreshLink


Set tdf = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetUNCLateBound(strMappedDrive As String) As String

Dim oFso  As Object
Dim strDrive As String
Dim strShare As String
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strMappedDrive = Trim(Replace(CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblDonations").Connect, 
";DATABASE=", ""))
strDrive = oFso.GetDriveName(strMappedDrive)
strShare = oFso.Drives(strDrive & "\").ShareName

GetUNCLateBound = Replace(strMappedDrive, strDrive, strShare)
'MsgBox (strMappedDrive)
 Set oFso = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Why would code not update to a different UNC string? It shouldn't care if path is already UNC. Have you step debugged?

Comment: @June7 when the links string is as `C:\Folder\backend.accdb`, the code executes fine but when it's `\\ServerName\Folder\backend.accdb`, and the location of the backend file changes, it runs but doesn't change the UNC. I did a debug but can't see any errors. About the loop, how do you iterate? Do I need to dim a string variable to hold the UNC before undating it? Thanks

Comment: @June7 sorry i forgot to add the `GetUNCLateBound` credit to @Steve Rindsberg please see updated code. I will try the looping soon as i figure out the fix.

Comment: It errors in line `strShare = oFso.Drives(strDrive & "\").ShareName`

Comment: Why is AllowMultiSelect set to True?

Comment: @June7 The `AllowMultiSelect` has now been corrected to `False`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
Sub RelinkTablesToBackend(BackEndPath As String)
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim db As Database
Dim tdfRefresh As TableDef
Dim strPath As String
Set db = CurrentDb
strPath = GetUNCLateBound(BackEndPath)
For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If tdf.Connect <> vbNullString Then
        On Error Resume Next
        tdf.Connect = Replace(tdf.Connect, Replace(tdf.Connect, ";DATABASE=", ""), strPath)
        tdf.RefreshLink
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            RelinkTablesToBackend = MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical + vbRetryCancel, "Error #:" & Err.Number)
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetUNCLateBound(strMappedDrive As String) As String
Dim oFso  As FileSystemObject
Dim strDrive As String
Dim strShare As String
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
GetUNCLateBound = strMappedDrive
If Left(strMappedDrive, 1) <> "C" Then
    strDrive = oFso.GetDriveName(strMappedDrive)
    strShare = oFso.Drives(strDrive).ShareName
    GetUNCLateBound = Replace(strMappedDrive, strDrive, strShare)
End If
Set oFso = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: this has helped but the`Dim oFso  As FileSystemObject` errors. `Dim oFso As Object` eliminates the error but I still get an error in line `strShare = oFso.Drives(strDrive).ShareName` for invalid procedure call or argument. The table link is currently in the UNC form. I was thinking about someting like `If strMappedDrive Like "*:*" Then
    strDrive = oFso.GetDriveName(strMappedDrive)
    strShare = oFso.Drives(strDrive & "\").ShareName
    Else ...`?

Comment: I tested with link already UNC and it worked. Since I cannot replicate issue, can't offer solution.

Comment: If you relocate the backend file and run the code again does it relink?

Comment: If so, do you mind sharing your test front end?

Comment: SO does not have utility for posting files. And I don't see how that would be helpful. You have the code. Yes, relinks after moving backend.

Comment: I see, I am trying to figure out why my code executes correctly in the first instance, but when I relocate the backend file and run it again, it fails. There is so much I have learned from you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have found a way to fix the problem by declaring a public variable which holds the updated path from a fileDialog and then using the variable in a loop. Please see my edit to your post.

Comment: The edit is held in peer review and am not sure if it can be released. But thank you

Comment: Finally realized I had call to GetUNCLateBound in wrong place. I was testing with only one table link so did not catch before. Edited my answer and since it didn't tell me there was already another edit pending, I suspect yours is gone. Public variable should not be needed with this change, although am still not sure why that fixed issue.

Comment: this works well. Wouldn't `Left(strMappedDrive, 2) <> ":"` or `strMappedDrive Like "*:*"` work regardless of the drive letter instead of `Left(strMappedDrive, 1) <> "C"`? Of course this is assuming `strMappedDrive` is always in the form `Letter:\Folder\file.accdb`.

Comment: When I did not test for drive C code failed. I could not map UNC for drive C. Test it - what happens for you? Yes, does assume user will always select a path that has drive letter. If you want to handle possibility of user selecting path through Network, modify code.

Comment: Really no need to replace drive C with UNC anyway. But if you do, I think would have to get computer name and replace `C:` with `\\thiscomputername` instead of ShareName. One way to get computer name is with `Environ("COMPUTERNAME")`. This is why I excluded drive C.